# ¿Como puedo mostrar un valor en vez de todo el texto de un listbox en c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, visual, listbox

Quiero mostrar un solo valor, de una base de datos al seleccionar un elemento del listbox.

agrege los elementos de una base de datos con:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Terreno:" + reader["no_terreno"].ToString() + " Manzana:" + reader["no_manzana"].ToString());
```

y al momento de dar doble clic use:

```
MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Mi problema es que al momento de seleccionar un elemento se muestra toda la cadena, y lo único que quiero es mostrar el numero de lote y la manzana. Ya en este listbox se mostraran los resultados de una busqueda, y al darle doble clic a los resultados, rellenara automáticamente otro Form.

**PD: los terrenos y manzanas son definidos por el usuario, ósea son aleatorios y pueden ser muchos mas de los mostrados en la imagen.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor el codigo en formato texto siempre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a dar dos opciones para que tomes la que tomas la opcion que mas te guste
Primero vemos que lo que muestras es un string por lo que tienes que modificar el el propio string 
[image: String on ADD]

Forma sencilla
Cuando haces el 
[image: show text]

puedes hacer substrings/replace en este caso te pongo el ejemplo de replace para que sea mas sencillo

```
var texto="terreno:16, Manzanas:13";
Console.WriteLine(texto.Replace("terreno:","").Replace("Manzanas:","")); //en vez de sacarlo por la consola como hago yo puedes sacarlo directamente en el show
```

La otra opción es crear una clase objeto y lo instancias con los métodos que necesites para que te retornen la información te dejo la documentación para que lo puedas revisar [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects)